# C# - Adding new control to the form screws up placement of other controls

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, resize, controls

In C# Windows Forms App I add a new control to the form during runtime in the form class:

```
this.Controls.Add( new Label() );
```

If I do this while the form in minimized, it screws up placement of other controls on the form, which have Anchor property set: they become larger than the form and I can't fix it by resizing the form.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: it only seems to affect controls which have Anchor property set to Right or Bottom or both.

Comment: Where do you expect the Label to appear if you haven't given any details on coordinates, size, anchoring, etc?

Comment: This is a test case. In my code I do give coordinates, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Please post the code you're actually using.

Comment: It is the code that I'm actually using at the moment. Beside of that I have a groupbox with Anchor property set to Top, Left, Right, Bottom in the GUI of VS. The timer runs the code that I posted. I minimize the form, the timer executes the code, I restore the window and groupbox growths to the right and to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding the new Label to a panel (or other container) that already exists and/or is Anchored.

```
this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label());
```

See the following article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984275(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I just tried this. I added a label at runtime to a groupbox that is anchored. It had a textbox inside it. After adding the new label while the form is minimized and restoring the form, the textbox became wider than the groubox.

Comment: The Anchor of that textbox is set to: top, left, right

Comment: The next step I would try is to SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout as show on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)